# apt-get won't remove or install anything due to mysql

Tags: installation, apt, package-management

I am attempting to update my system using apt-get and the package manager. When I run update, I get an error about mysql dependencies. As I do not care about mysql I attempt to 'purge' it - this is what I get:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I do sudo apt-get -f install it gives the following which seems similar:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblash3 libcommons-jxpath-java libmaven-dependency-tree-java
  libjaxp1.3-java junit4 libgnustep-base1.20 libplexus-archiver-java
  libmaven-filtering-java librhino-java extra-xdg-menus
  libplexus-containers-java libmaven-compiler-plugin-java libwagon-java
  libappframework-java libmodello-java libgeronimo-jms-1.1-spec-java libunity4
  libdb4.7-java libunity6 libmaven-resources-plugin-java
  libplexus-compiler-javac-java libplexus-classworlds-java libmaven2-core-java
  libx264-116 libfile-homedir-perl libhttpclient-java libservlet2.4-java antlr
  libcommons-beanutils-java libxom-java libxalan2-java libcommons-jexl-java
  zeitgeist-extension-fts libecal1.2-8 g++-4.5 junit libplexus-cipher-java
  libtextcat-data libdom4j-java libxpp2-java libasm2-java default-jdk-doc
  libdee-1.0-1 libplexus-component-api-java libplexus-build-api-java
  libplexus-i18n-java libutouch-geis1 libplexus-interactivity-api-java
  libqdox-java libncurses5-dev libstdc++6-4.5-dev libnspr4-0d:i386 libsqlite0
  libswingx-java libcommons-cli-java java-wrappers libjaxen-java
  libunity-misc0 libindicator3-6 gir1.2-vte-0.0 gir1.2-appindicator-0.1
  libxbean-java libcommons-net2-java libgadu3 libswingworker-java
  libmaven-clean-plugin-java libsaxon-java libfolks22 jruby1.1 lib32ffi6
  libitext1-java libdb5.1-java libcommons-collections-java libgegl-0.0-0
  libindicator3 libindicator6 libplexus-ant-factory-java
  libplexus-container-default-java default-jdk libjsch-java libtinfo-dev bsh
  libplexus-compiler-manager-java libgdata11 libeasymock-java
  libplexus-compiler-api-java fop libedata-cal1.2-10 libjaxme-java
  libedata-book1.2-8 libfm-gtk0 libbsf-java libgwibber1 libnekohtml-java
  libplexus-io-java libplexus-bsh-factory-java libclassworlds-java
  libedataserverui1.2-11 eagle-data libplexus-interpolation-java
  libgoogle-collections-java libplexus-digest-java gcj-4.5-base
  libgdata1.7-cil libminiupnpc5 libpoppler-glib6 libantlr-java libjdom1-java
  libhttpcore-java libmaven-file-management-java libtextcat0 libfm0
  libservlet2.3-java libmaven-jar-plugin-java libcommons-vfs-java libxpp3-java
  libjsr305-java libjsoup-java libjpeg62:i386 libquvi0 libregexp-java
  lib32ncursesw5 libfop-java libplexus-compiler-java
  libcommons-configuration-java rhino libnl3 libgtkspell3-0
  libboost-serialization1.42.0 libcamel1.2-19 libxmlgraphics-commons-java
  libwerken.xpath-java gir1.2-dee-0.5 libavahi-compat-libdnssd1
  libhamcrest-java libmaven-archiver-java libnetbeans-cvsclient-java
  libequinox-osgi-java libobjc2 libcommons-collections3-java
  libplexus-utils-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libmaven-scm-java
  libdoxia-java libfolks-telepathy22 libcommons-digester-java libbatik-java
  libbackport-util-concurrent-java libmaven-install-plugin-java
  libmaven-shared-io-java libnatpmp1 python-wsgi-intercept libjline-java
  libcommons-io-java libpoppler13 libnss3-1d:i386 icc-profiles-free
  liboverlay-scrollbar-0.1-0 libebook1.2-10 libllvm2.9 libllvm2.9:i386
  libganymed-ssh2-java
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 191 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,867 kB of archives.
After this operation, 57.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2); however:
  Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

-- at this point I am at a loss...I can't remove the offending packages, attempting to configure them seems to throw errors and attempting to finish their install seems to throw errors. And apt-get and the package manager app won't do anything - will not install any updates whatsoever, even security relevant ones, without first throwing this error. How do I make this go away?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
```

Comment: You can click the checkmark to accept the answer (if not now then soon.)